# Cannot set custom margins for <ul>

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I'm attempting to set custom margins for an unordered-list, however, the list continues to be stuck to the top left corner of the div. Basically, I'd like the `ul` to be about 20% from the right side of the page.
HTML:

```
<body>
            <div id="nav"> 
                <span class="nav">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#myAnchor" rel="" id="anchor1" class="anchorLink">HOME</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/">WORK</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/">ABOUT</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
    </body>
```

CSS:

```
body { 
  background: url(img/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

#nav {
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px rgba(60, 60, 60, 1);
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    background-color: #000000;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
}

.nav ul {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    left: 50%;
}

.nav ul li{
    padding-right: 40px;
    display: inline;    
}

.nav ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px rgba(60, 60, 60, 1);
}

.nav ul li a:hover {
    text-decoration: overline;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px rgba(60, 60, 60, 1);
}ode here`
```

Comment: There are many wrongs with your code. Span tag isn't closed (and from where I see it, useless anyway) and in you css you don't specify a margin but a position, which won't work on relatively positionned elements like your list. Try margin-left instead...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make the ul float to the right :

```
.nav ul {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 20%;
}
```

Here's a demo : http://jsfiddle.net/wzsq3b5z/

By the way, your "left: 50%;" is useless, since your list is not placed in "absolute" positioning.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Worked 100%

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problems here.

One has already been pointed out, which is that you never closed your `<span>`, but the main problem here is that you are trying to use the `left` property to move your `<ul>`, which won't affect initial positioned elements.

You need to change that to relative, fixed, or absolute for that to matter.

---

An easy fix: set `text-align` to right for the `<ul>`. You can then use `margin-right` to set how far from the right side you want the `<ul>`.

## [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lu2u6ksa/)

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have some problems in you HTML, like an opened `<span>` tag and a block element `<ul>` inside an inline element `<span>`. I just took the liberty to fix that code for you:

Here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/o1y9bwuz/

HTML:

```
<body>
    <ul id="nav">
        <li><a href="#myAnchor" rel="" id="anchor1" class="anchorLink">HOME</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="/">WORK</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="/">ABOUT</a>

        </li>
    </ul>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    background: url(img/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
#nav {
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px rgba(60, 60, 60, 1);
    font-family:'Oswald', sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    background-color: #000000;
    top: 0;
    right: 20%;
    position: fixed;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
#nav li {
    padding-right: 40px;
    display: inline;
}
#nav li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px rgba(60, 60, 60, 1);
}
#nav li a:hover {
    text-decoration: overline;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px rgba(60, 60, 60, 1);
}
```